# Excepcion en python que no se como arreglar

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, calculo

Estoy usando anaconda python 3.7.6 con el ide spyder

al ejecutar mi codigo en una terminal de IPython

me da el siguiente error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpleeval.py", line 431, in _eval_name
    return self.names[node.id]

KeyError: 'h'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\santiago\.spyder-py3\Calculus.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Users\santiago\.spyder-py3\Calculus.py", line 51, in main
    main()

  File "C:\Users\santiago\.spyder-py3\Calculus.py", line 50, in main
    print(f"el resultado es:  {simple_eval(calc)}")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpleeval.py", line 609, in simple_eval
    return s.eval(expr)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpleeval.py", line 332, in eval
    return self._eval(ast.parse(expr.strip()).body[0].value)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpleeval.py", line 343, in _eval
    return handler(node)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpleeval.py", line 443, in _eval_name
    raise NameNotDefined(node.id, self.expr)

NameNotDefined: 'h' is not defined for expression 'h'
```

estoy usando un modulo que encontre buscando un reemplazamiento de eval, se llama simpleeval

siempre que pongo una letra y no una operacion me salta este error

al hacer operaciones numericas no pasa nada pero no se como usar el Except: para detener este NameNotDefined

este es mi codigo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

Created on Thu Apr  2 16:48:55 2020

@author: santiago
"""


from simpleeval import simple_eval


print("Bienvenido a Calculus")
print("si quieres ayuda pon 'ayuda'")
print("si quieres salir pon 'salir'")
#############################################

def ayuda():
    print("""
                  --- Menu Ayuda ---
                  operadores usables:
                      suma = +
                      resta = -
                      division = /
                      multiplicacion = *
                      raiz cuadrada = **
                      ejemplo: 3**3 = es 3 elevado a la tercera
          """)
    input("presiona enter para salir ")
    main()

def salir():
    print("¿Estas seguro de que queres salir? (s/n)")
    opc = input("si o no> ").lowercase()
    if opc == "si" or opc == "s":
        exit()
    else:
        main()




def main():
    try:
        calc = input("Calculus>")
        if calc == "ayuda":
            ayuda()

        else:
            print(f"el resultado es:  {simple_eval(calc)}")
            main()

    except IndexError or KeyError:
        print(f"""
              {calc} no es un comando
              para ayuda pon 'ayuda'""")

while True:
    main()
```

como no hay un presunto 'NameNotDefined' en los errores no puedo usar el comando 'except:'

toda sugerencia para arreglarlo se acepta

si el error no se puede solucionar solo diganlo porfavor eso ayudaria mucha

Answer (score 1):

El tipo de excepción es una clase más, puedes importarla del módulo que la genera:

```
from simpleeval import simple_eval, NameNotDefined

try:
    # ....
except NameNotDefined as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Por otro lado, si quieres manejar varios tipos de excepciones en un mismo `except`:

```
except IndexError or KeyError:
```

es incorrecto, debes hacer:

```
except (IndexError, KeyError):
```

Comment: lo probare! parece que funcionara